# Memory from AVAudioPlayer in ivar not reused

Tags: ios, memory-management, avaudioplayer

I've set up an instance variable to reference an AVAudioPlayer that I'm using to play different audio data at different times. My header file contains:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

And my implementation file contains:

```
- (void)playAudioData:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableData *trimmedData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:data];
    int duration = 2; // seconds
    int dataLength = duration * 2 * 44100; // assumes 16-bit mono data
    [trimmedData setLength:dataLength];

    NSError *playerError;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:trimmedData error:&playerError];
    [self.player autorelease]; // ADDED
    if (playerError) {
        NSLog(@"player error: %@", playerError);
    }
    [self.player play];
    if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0"] != NSOrderedAscending)&&([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.1"] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
        [trimmedData autorelease]; // ADDED
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.player release];
}
```

When profiling my app for memory usage, I've noticed that calling this method increases the live bytes by 500k, which is about the size of the audio data I'm playing. However, if I call the method again, the live bytes increases by another 500k, and another, each time I call the method.

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7087530/462162), I shouldn't have to do anything differently here because setting the self.player variable reduces the retain count of the existing value. But I also tried releasing and setting self.player to nil before giving it a new value, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932944/462162), and autoreleasing self.player after setting it, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766022/462162). (I'm not getting errors initializing the player, as was the issue in that last answer.) In all these cases, my memory usage keeps going up and never comes down again.

Is there something else I need to do to reuse the memory that is allocated each time I initialize the audio player?

Comment: Since you're explicitly calling release, I'll assume you're not using ARC. In that case, the code you posted does leak the audio player. You should autorelease the player when you allocate it. If that really doesn't fix the problem then something else is wrong. Does instruments show a leak, or just an increasing memory footprint?

Comment: Also, where does that `NSData` come from? That code is suspect as well...

Comment: Your hunch about the NSData was a good one. In fact, I'm trimming that data by creating a new NSMutableData from it ... I just edited my answer to show what I mean. I thought this was irrelevant because I thought the dataWithData method would create an autoreleased object. However, if I manually release trimmedData object at the end of this method, the memory usage behaves as expected: it goes up when initializing the player, and drops back down when the player stops. So now, do I really need to autorelease the player? Instruments doesn't show a leak.

Comment: Well, that's still odd. `dataWithData` does return an autoreleased object. You shouldn't need to release it. And you'll only have officially leaked your player when you call `playAudioData` a second time. If your player is never being deallocated, and it was the sole owner of that `trimmedData`, you sending it an extra `release` would cause the data to be reclaimed, despite the player living on. One last nit-pick, in your `dealloc` you should set `self.player` to `nil` instead of explicitly releasing it.

Comment: It is odd. I found that I get the same result with [trimmedData autorelease] as with [trimmedData release]. So apparently the data is not autoreleasing unless I tell it to. Also, I tried to manually release the player each time I created a new one, rather than leaving it to an autorelease, but the memory is not reclaimed with a manual release. So I updated my question to show the only combination that worked for me: autoreleasing the player instead of manually releasing it, and explicitly autoreleasing the data instead of relying on the normal autorelease behavior.

Comment: Mystery solved: it looks like my NSMutableData is erroneously retained in iOS 6.0.x, but not in iOS 5 or iOS 6.1, which behave as expected (and in which my extra autorelease causes a crash). I updated my question one more time in case anyone copies this code into a project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my app before switching to `Automatic Reference Counting` [ARC], memory usage will increase until the app crashes, right?. The fastest way for you to fix this problem is to use ARC too in your app/project, in fact it will do all the job of managing memory and release `AVAudioPlayer` when needed [you don't need any `-void(dealloc)` in your code if you use ARC], so no more leaks :-). If you don't know what ARC is you can check this link too:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

**Header:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer           *player;

    /* Your other code here */
}

/* Your other code here */

@end
```

**Main:**

```
#import "YourViewController.h"

@implementation YourViewController

/* Your other code here */

- (void)playAudioData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *playerError;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&playerError]; error:NULL];

    if (playerError)
    {
        NSLog(@"player error: %@", playerError);
    }

    [self.player play];

    /* No more need to release AVAudioPlayer, ARC will do the job */

}

/* Your other code here */

@end
```

Comment: Eh ... wouldn't that require some major rework of my already large and complex app?

Comment: @arlomedia You can try with XCode's Automatic Conversion, it will convert your code to support ARC in just a few clicks and totally automatic [it will also remove the unnecessary code like "release"], in the link before there's a paragraph about that called "Automated Conversion" check it :-). XCode will do a snapshot of your project too so if you're not happy about ARC you can revert all the changes instantly

Comment: The automated conversion tool works pretty well and easy, too!